# Problems with cache queryset django rest framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

Good day to all, I have been trying to make this query be consulted every time the REST service is used in the API, but only the first time it obtains the data from the DB and when the data changes the service only brings the cache stored data

My Code:
urls.py

```
router.register(r'cron-log',views.CronLogViewSet, base_name='cron-log')
```

Views.py - my viewset class

```
class CronLogViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Cron_log.objects.all().order_by('-id').values()[:5:1]
serializer_class = CronLogSerializer
```

Models.py my model class from Cron_log

```
class Cron_log(models.Model):
log = models.CharField(max_length=40)
time = models.CharField(max_length=40)
def as_dict(self):
    return {'log':self.log,'time':self.time}
```

Serializer.py serializer class

```
class CronLogSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Cron_log
    fields = ('log','time')
```

I tried with a for before the queryset, with list(query_set) but the issue still there thanks! for your help

Answer (score 3):

The QuerySet is not updating for a couple reasons. 1. It is being evaluated with a slice that uses the `step` parameter (the `step` parameter is the `1` in `[:5:1]` (which is superfluous as 1 is the default - unless you want to trigger an evaluation)). 2. It is evaluated only once in the class body definition which does not update every time an instance of the viewset is initialized.  See the Django documentation's section on [when querysets are evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) for more information regarding slicing.

If you want the viewset to always return an updated queryset of objects limited to the first 5 ordered by descending id, one option is to place the limit slice in a `get_queryset` instance method that returns the queryset limited to the first 5 results.

```
class CronLogViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Cron_log.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    serializer_class = CronLogSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(CronLogViewSet, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.values()[:5]
```

See the Django Rest Framework documentation's section on [filtering](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering) and, more specifically, the implementation of [`views.GenericAPIView.get_queryset`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/cdb8a3c3c86bbb74f17f8880c52000602b015ed4/rest_framework/generics.py#L50-L75) for more information.